# What is the source of the plum flavor in (this) plum porter?

Tags: specialty-beers, flavor, porter

I had a plum porter lately, it has a really intense plum flavor and aroma and even a bit of plums in the taste, so I thought there were some plum products in it. However, there is nothing in ingredients list which could give the plum note to the drink.

How does the plum falvor originate here?

[image: Plum Porte ingridients]

Comment: I don’t know the labeling laws in the UK. Perhaps you could contact the brewery and then answer your own question.

Comment: @EricS Thanks for the idea. I actually did it and they said they use plum extract.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I contacted the brewery and they replied that

> To get the plum flavour we use a natural plum extract.

Curious that it's not on the ingredients list.

PS. It's [St.Peter's Plum Porter](https://www.stpetersbrewery.co.uk/products/Plum-Porter-p208337012).

Comment: Good job. It is perfectly fine to accept your own answer.

Comment: @EricS Yes, but it's only possible after 5 hours :)

Answer (score 2):

It's probably a combination of certain hops and yeasts. Some kinds of ale yeasts are known to add a plummy flavour to a beer (WLP500 for example). And also hops like golding or empire can go into this direction.

The dominant exotic fruit taste in e.g. IPAs usually also doesn't originate from actual fruits, but from hops and yeast.

Comment: Assuming it’s this beer, I’m pretty sure it’s made with plums. https://www.titanicbrewery.co.uk/shop/plum-porter-bottle/

Comment: Maybe Altbier can clarify which beer it is, because Titanic Plum Porter contains natural plum flavouring, this is stated everywhere online, and I'm sure, also on the label.

Comment: It's [St.Peter's Plum Porter](https://www.stpetersbrewery.co.uk/products/Plum-Porter-p208337012).